# iOS Error - "unrecognized selector"

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, twitter-oauth, unrecognized-selector

Main.m

```
NSDictionary *additionalQueryParameters = [NSURL ab_parseURLQueryString:[url query]];
```

OAuth.h

```
@interface NSURL (OAuthAdditions)

+ (NSDictionary *)ab_parseURLQueryString:(NSString *)query;

@end
```

OAuth.m

```
@implementation NUSL (OAuthAdditions)

+ (NSDictionary *)ab_parseURLQueryString:(NSString *)query
{
 does something..
}
```

When it runs that line, it throws this error...

> 2012-12-03 15:10:58.506[12500:1d403] +[NSURL ab_parseURLQueryString:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to class 0xaece26c
>
> 2012-12-03 15:10:58.508[12500:1d403] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSURL
>   ab_parseURLQueryString:]: unrecognized selector sent to class
>   0xaece26c'
>
> *** First throw call stack: (0xada8012 0xa3d6e7e 0xae332ad 0xad97bbc 0xad9794e 0x17b5ee8 0x17b5724 0x17b58d6 0xa84f53f 0xa861014 0xa8522e8
>   0xa851fcb 0x96097b24 0x960996fe) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called
>   throwing an exception

Any idea why it can't find it and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Is the method in OAuth.m within `@implementation (OAuthAdditions)`?

Comment: Lack of an import would barf a compiler warning, but not a runtime error.

Comment: Is the OAuth.m target membership correct?

Comment: yes I did import the .h file to the class that's using it.

Comment: None of the answers below solved this question

Answer (score 1):

Make sure OAuth.m is actually in the target and building in your project....

Comment: I checked the files location and it's in my project - does that confirm that it's in the target and building?

Comment: No. Select the .m file in the project navigator. Then click on the View menu and select Utilities then Show File Inspector. In the file inspector, look at the Target Membership section. Make sure the appropriate targets are checked.

Answer (score 1):

Your category implementation (OAuth.m) is named NUSL, not NSURL. The compiler is fine with the method since the category interface (header) is named correctly.